# horizontal plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, orientation

I am looking for a plot that is rotated 90 degree in clockwise directions. An similar example of such plot is "hist(x,  orientation='horizontal')". Is there any way to achieve similar orientation.

```
#Make horizontal plots.
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = random.sample(range(1000), 100)
x
plt.plot(x) #orientation='horizontal'
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.plot(x)` plots your x values automatically against the y-axis. In order to get a rotated plot you have to plot your x values against the x axis. So you'll need a to make vector for the y-axis, which has the same length as your sample.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=random.sample(1000)
y=np.arange(1000)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Using `plt.plot(x)`, matplotlib takes your x-values as its y-values and generates a vector for the x axis automatically.